# React-Native onLayout not smooth

Tags: react-native

I have a onLayout on a Gallery screen, but when I rotate the screen, when it calls the onLayout it's not smooth at all. Even on a real device it's laggy.
[Here](https://vid.me/hhE3A) is a video showing the problem.

I can even see part of other screen when rotating. Is there any other way to make the screen rotate smoothly?

onLayout:

```
  onLayout = event => {
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
    this.setState({width, height})
  }
```

then I have onLayout on my container view. And on other views and images, I have a conditional render.

For example:

```
height:(height > width) ? 500 : responsiveHeight(80)
```

EDIT: First screen is the only one that renders correctly, the children screens always lag.